# SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::powerOn

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Do you know when the return value will come back if I call API: "Power On/powerOff/powerRecycle" of SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest? Will it return instantly or wait for the execution finished for "power on/power off/power recycle"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return immediately to notify that the request was executed successfully.